# How to copy Jenkins secret files

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have already added 2 secret files to Jenkins credentials with names `PRIVATE-KEY` and `PUBLIC-KEY`. 
How can I copy those 2 files to `/src/resources` directory inside a job?

I have the following snippet

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'PRIVATE_KEY', variable: 'my-private-key'),
                 file(credentialsId: 'PUBLIC_KEY', variable: 'my-public-key')]) {
   //how to copy, where are those files to copy from?
}
```

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Ok, I think I managed to do it. `my-private-key` variable is a path to the secret, so I had to copy that secret to the destination I needed.

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'PRIVATE_KEY', variable: 'my-private-key'),
                 file(credentialsId: 'PUBLIC_KEY', variable: 'my-public-key')]) {
   sh "cp \$my-public-key /src/main/resources/my-public-key.der"
   sh "cp \$my-private-key /src/main/resources/my-private-key.der"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back with a solution, it was helpful to me.

Comment: thanks humberd, yeah i think the ability to dump to your preferred filename would be a good enhancement. the [config file plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/config-file-provider/) provides that option.

Comment: Please be warned that your approach leaves the copied files in place on the build node after the Credentials block has closed.  Any subsequent steps will still have access to the file contents.  Remember that withCredential blocks are privilege access blocks.

Answer (score 25):

Both solutions are good for a specific OS (*win, unix*). There are some basic functions to check is system unix `isUnix()`. Instead of this you can use the `read/write` basic methods for any machine.

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: PRIVATE_KEY, variable: 'my_private_key'),
             file(credentialsId: PUBLIC_KEY, variable: 'my_public_key')]) {
    writeFile file: 'key/private.pem', text: readFile(my_private_key)
    writeFile file: 'key/public.pem', text: readFile(my_public_key)
}
```

Comment: This is a clean solution, but I got an unwanted character when tried with an XML file.

Answer (score 2):

Following on from @[Humberds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4256929/humberd) answer, the equivalent for `powershell` is:

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'PRIVATE_KEY', variable: 'my-private-key')]) {
  bat "powershell Copy-Item $appSettings -Destination src\\main\\resources "
}
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the above solutions worked for me so here is my workaround. Maybe someone finds it helpful. The path of my secret file contains spaces so I had to use quotes (but it took me a while to figure out it was an issue).

```
pipeline {
  agent any
  stages {
    stage('GetCred') {
      steps {
        script {
          withCredentials([
            file(
              credentialsId: 'YourCredential',
              variable: 'credvar')
          ]) {
            sh 'cp "\$credvar" file'
            sh 'cat file'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is an answer to another problem

Answer (score 0):

```
withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: 'your-credentials-id', keyFileVariable: 'PRIVATE_KEY_FILE')]) {  
    sh "cat ${PRIVATE_KEY_FILE} > credentials.txt"  
}
```