# How do I download a jenkins secret file from the credential store?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I can only upload an existing jenkins secret file not download the existing one.

How do I download an existing secret file I uploaded to confirm its contents?

Comment: I don't think that's a valid argument here. This is an administrative feature that is missing. It should be up to the admin to secure admin access to Jenkins and Jenkins should allow admins to view secrets. Vault and other modern secrets managers have this ability

Comment: See also similar question to download/copy the secret file so that it can be used in the workspace: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49460520/how-to-copy-jenkins-secret-files

Answer (score 37, accepted):

In case you can access your Jenkins instance's Script Console (e.g. by visiting https://jenkins.example.com/script in a browser), you can run the following script:

```
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.*;
import com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.domains.Domain;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.plaincredentials.impl.FileCredentialsImpl;

println "Jenkins credentials config file location=" + SystemCredentialsProvider.getConfigFile();
println ""

def fileName = "my-secret-file.txt"

SystemCredentialsProvider.getInstance().getCredentials().stream().
  filter { cred -> cred instanceof FileCredentialsImpl }.
  map { fileCred -> (FileCredentialsImpl) fileCred }.
  filter { fileCred -> fileName.equals( fileCred.getFileName() ) }.
  forEach { fileCred -> 
    String s = new String( fileCred.getSecretBytes().getPlainData() )
    println "XXXXXX BEGIN a secret file with fileName=" + fileName + " XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    println s
    println "XXXXXX END a secret file with fileName=" + fileName + " XXXXXXXXXXXX"
    println ""
  }
```

Change `fileName` to the file name you would like to print out.
This script will print out the contents of files in Jenkins credentials store's global domain that have `fileName` as file name.

Fixable caveats of this script:

- Requires that Jenkins is running in a Java 8 JVM.
  This script.
- Looks in the *global credential domain* only (see https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/credentials/com/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/SystemCredentialsProvider.html#getCredentials-- ).

Comment: perfect. Question though, does this write the file to a temp location or can I be sure it doesn't leave it anywhere after it reads. Also, how do I get other secrets like secure strings and username/passwords like this? i tried just using `StringCredentialsImpl` but it no work

Answer (score 6):

If you have shell access to and *sudo*/`root`/*Jenkins Unix user* permissions on the machine running Jenkins, you can retrieve the secret file by doing the following:

- In some Jenkins job that has permissions to access the secret file, select *Configure*.
- On the *Configuration* interface, under *Build Environment*, select *Use secret text(s) or file(s)*.
- Click *Add* -> *Secret file*. This creates a new *Secret file* binding.
- Select *Specific credentials*, then from the drop-down menu below it select the secret file you would like to retrieve. Let's assume your secret file is stored under the filename *my-secret-file.txt*.
- Assign to this secret file a *variable* e.g. `MY_SECRET_FILE_TXT`.
- Now, under *Pre Steps*, click *Add pre-build step* -> *Execute shell*.
- In the *Command* text area, add the following shell script:

  ```
  echo "executing user is $(whoami)"

  # remove my-secret-file.txt before possibly getting an overwriting error
  rm -f $WORKSPACE/my-secret-file.txt

  echo "Jenkins project workspace: $WORKSPACE"
  cp $MY_SECRET_FILE_TXT $WORKSPACE
  ```
- Click *Save* to save this configuration.

The next time a build is triggered for this project, the secret file should appear in this project's workspace, i.e. at location `$WORKSPACE/my-secret-file.txt`. As an example, on my *Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS* installation with installed package and daemon`jenkins`, that location is `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/$JENKINS_PROJECT_NAME/my-secret-file.txt`

Comment: So i could hack it like this, but I looking for a more convenient way of doing this. Id even prefer manually decrypting secrets from the command line- is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

I usually extract secrets from jenkins by creating a job like this:

[image]

Jenkins masks all the keys in the output, so just replace one character when you print it out.  If it turns out there is another `0` in your key, it'll appear as `*******` and you can try replacing a different character, or splitting it in two and printing the two halfs on different lines, or another similar trick.

You can also just stick it straight into a file like this.

```
echo $HELLO > slack-key.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

The marked answer with the script console is great.

There is also this script that will list ALL secrets that can be run from the console too:
https://github.com/tkrzeminski/jenkins-groovy-scripts/blob/master/show-all-credentials.groovy