# How to copy a .properties file to jenkins workspace, so that it can be used by the python script

Tags: python, jenkins

I am trying to run a python project through Jenkins. I am providing some connection details to the project
through a .properties file. It works absolutely fine when I directly run it in code editor or command prompt. Where as,
when I try to run the same through Jenkins (installed locally in my Windows machine), it throws error for the function which reads the .property file, saying FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
Can anyone suggest, how can I can I make it work.

Comment: Can you verify that the .properties file is located in the workspace of the Jenkins job you are running? https://stackoverflow.com/a/34918545/5630865

Comment: It wasnt there. So I manually copied it to there. But I want to know, how to copy using winodows batch command. So that each time I change the property file, it automatically gets copies to the Workspace while taking the build.

Comment: You could try out the Credentials Binding plugin and use its "secret file" option to select your .properties file and inject that secret . In case this would be static (didn't test it myself yet) and you definitely want it to be dynamically updated on each build, IMO you could try the following alternative: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49466478/5630865